# Get file from server and convert it to byte array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binaryfiles

In javascript I want to download(get) binary files from server and use its bytes.
I use this code:

```
$.get('/file.mp4', function(data) {
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
        }
    });
```

But there is a problem: some characters of *data* variable have ASCII code grater than 255 (like "ą" --> ASCII:261)!! and charCodeAt(i) return 65533 for them also when i use `console.log(data[i])` output is "�".

I tested `"ą".charCodeAt(0)` and output was 261 so I guess that problem is in *data* that received by *get* method not in *charCodeAt* method. Is there an alternative method to download binary files??

Comment: did you tried Uint16Array/Uint32Array ?

Comment: you can request `arrayBuffer` in `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: @MatteoRubini Yes I have tried them but problem has not been solved yet.

Comment: http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: @JaromandaX so many thanks. The problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fetch data like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/my/image/name.png', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    // get binary data as a response
    var blob = this.response;
  }
};

xhr.send();
```